# Make button disappear when clicked

Tags: javascript, php

I have the following code:

```
<script>
    function hidenow(id) {
        var divelement = document.getElementById(id);

        if(divelement.style.display == 'none')
                divelement.style.display =='block'; 
        else
                divelement.style.display = 'none';
                hidenow = button.style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
</script>
```

And

```
<br>
<p>Programma's waarop u kunt abonneren:</p>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td id="hideit" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <?php
                 echo $alreadysub; echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->Anaam );
                 ?>
                 </td>
                <th>
                    <button id="hidebutton('hideb')" onclick="hidenow('hideit')" name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

And

```
<br> 
<p>De programma's waarop u geabonneerd bent:</p>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programmatest_action', 'set_programmatest' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td style="vertical-align: middle;"><?php echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->meta_value ); ?></td>
                <th>
                    <button name="programmatest" type="submit" id="button" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->meta_value ); ?>">Abonnement opzeggen</button>
                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } 
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

When the button is clicked, the element successfully disappears. The button however, does not. I do not know how to make sure the button itself also disappears. I have tried `onClick = button.style.visibility = "hidden";` but it does not give any result.

How can I make sure that when I click the button, the button itself along with the element disappear (permanently)?

[image]

Comment: `id="hidebutton('hideb')"` You probably want an actual ID there that you would pass through on your onClick.

Comment: If this is the `click` event handler for the button and you want the clicked button to be affected, just use `this` to reference that button in your event handler.

Comment: ^ This is the correct way to do it. Considering your button is in a loop, doing the method you have now would create multiples of the same id. Using `this` would allow it to get the exact button.

Answer (score 0):

change

`<button id="hidebutton('hideb')" onclick="hidenow('hideit')" name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>`

to

`<button id="hide" onclick="hidenow('hide')" name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>`

You can't set a ID as a function (I'm assuming that's what you tried to do)

That should fix it

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

If you want to hide button after the form is submitted just set the `isset($_POST['programma'` if you set it do not show button if form is not submitted it will show.

replace your button code with code below.

```
if (isset($_POST['programma'])) {
  echo "";
} else  {
  echo '<button id="hidebutton" style="display:block" name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>';
}
```

Other wise you would need to store information if form is submitted in cookie or PHP Session and after reading that info show hide based on that with PHP/JS.

```js
    function hidenow(id) {
        var divelement = document.getElementById(id);
         var button = document.getElementById("hidebutton");

        if(divelement.style.display == 'none')
                divelement.style.display ='block',
                button.style.display = "block";
        else
                divelement.style.display = 'none',
                button.style.display = "none";
    }
```

```html
<br>
<p>Programma's waarop u kunt abonneren:</p>
<form action="#" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    <?php wp_nonce_field( 'set_programma_action', 'set_programma' ); ?>
    <table>
        <?php foreach ( $retrieve_data as $retrieved_data ) { ?>
            <tr>
                <th>Programma:</th>
                <td id="hideit" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                <?php
                 echo $alreadysub; echo esc_html( $retrieved_data->Anaam );
                 ?>
                 </td>
                <th>

                </th>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </table>
</form>
                    <button id="hidebutton" style="display:block" onclick="hidenow('hideit')" name="programma" type="submit" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $retrieved_data->Anaam ); ?>">Abonneer</button>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. It works. However, the button is misplaced and the button underneath it is not there anymore. Check the new edit please.

Comment: Also, the button does not go permamently.

Comment: @Parsa_237 I don't  understand what you are talking about. I moved the button out of the form so the form wont get submitted for demonstration purposes.  And i don't understand what "he button does not go permanently" means. You wanted it hidden, its hidden.

Comment: First problem is solved. The problem is that as soon as the data is submitted to the database, the button along with the element is not hidden anymore

Comment: @Parsa_237 That is complicity different story. You need echo the button based on some PHP if condition from data from database or store this info in PHP session or cookie. Basically you need the way of storing info if user has submitted form or not. then hide button with PHP or JS. This is not enough of relevant info to help you with that.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the edit. This removes both buttons when clicked and now I am not able to insert the data in the database.

Comment: @Parsa_237 I see only one button in your HTML code you posted.

Comment: Hi, do you know how I can make sure both buttons do not dissapear? But only the one I need? I also added the code of my second button.